# unable to iterate over elements in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Im a selenium noob and have been struggling to get things done with python.
Im trying to iterate over all user reviews("partial_entry" class) from this page https://www.tripadvisor.com/Airline_Review-d8729164-Reviews-Cheap-Flights-or560-TAP-Portugal#REVIEWS

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\shalini\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
url="https://www.tripadvisor.com/Airline_Review-d8729164-Reviews-Cheap-Flights-or560-TAP-Portugal#REVIEWS"
driver.get(url)

for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='wrap']"):
    print i.find_element(By.XPATH, '//p[@class="partial_entry"]')
        print i.text
    print "=============================================="
    # THIS IF BLOCK IS NECESSARY, I CANT DO AWAY WITH THIS ONE
    if i.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#REVIEWS .googleTranslation>.link"):
        print "======YES TRANSLATION AVAILABLE========"
```

Even though Im selecting a different element each time in for loop, but its printing the same element over and over again. (I have to keep the last if block & cant do away with it, so whatever the solution be it has to include that if block also)

======EDIT===================

Even this isnt working (which should actually work, according to http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html ) . I dont know whats going on with selenium !!!!!

```
print i.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p.partial_entry')
```

Output:

```
NoSuchElementException:
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Iterating on element with some class, attribute etc. tells us nothing about what are you exactly trying to do. You can say something like, I am trying to iterate and print all the 4 star reviews or click all the suggested links etc.

Comment: @testerjoe2 I trying to print all user reviews ("partial_entry" class)

Comment: when I am running your code its prininting elemnts like this.....<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bad694f93df4dc5a910a568a91dd154d", element="0.04415381477050029-25")>
Reviewed February 1, 2016
Andre_Barbosa_83, Joao Pessoa, PB
==============================================
its prinint different reviews as expected ..what you want to print

Comment: @thebadguy can you help me with another question ?

Comment: @shalini ..yes...which question

Comment: @thebadguy  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069726/python-selenium-loops-over-unnecessary-elements

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.** The reason you keep getting the first element repeatedly while iterating over `i.find_element(By.XPATH, '//p[@class="partial_entry"]')` in the 2nd loop is that the beginning `//` tries to locate elements from the root/top level, *not* as a descendant element of `i`. So that just keeps returning the first `p.partial_entry` element for each iteration of the outer loop.

To search for descendant elements of `i` which match `p[@class="partial_entry"]`, the xpath should start with `.//`. That's what the dot does.

**2.** For the line `print i.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p.partial_entry')`:
The single `find_element` either return the first found element or throw an error if none are found. There are some 'div.wrap's which don't have that descendant element, so you will get `NoSuchElementException`.

The `find_elements` (note the 's') methods return a list of elements or an empty list if none are found, rather than an error.

So putting all that together:

```
>>> for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='wrap']"):
...     for ent in i.find_elements_by_xpath('.//p[@class="partial_entry"]'):
...         print ent.text
...         if i.find_elements_by_css_selector('#REVIEWS .googleTranslation>.link'):
...             print 'translation available'
...     print  # output clarity
...
```

---

Btw, why are you mixing things like `find_elements_by_xpath('...')` along with `find_element(By.XPATH, '...')`? Stick to one pattern.