# How do i iterate through a webelements list with Python and Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to iterate through a webelements list and return the text from each of them but i only get the text from the first `<h2>`element and not from the rest elements that are inside the other `<li>` tags, and then the code exist that loop

Here is part of the Html code from which i want to extract the text:

```html
<div class="KambiBC-event-page-component__column KambiBC-event-page-component__column--1">
  
            <ul class="KambiBC-list-view__column">
              <li class="KambiBC-bet-offer-category KambiBC-collapsible-container KambiBC-expanded KambiBC-bet-offer-category--hidden KambiBC-bet-offer-category--fade-in">
                <header class="KambiBC-bet-offer-category__header" data-touch-feedback="true">
                  <h2 class="KambiBC-bet-offer-category__title js-bet-offer-category-title">Piete selectate</h2>
                </header>
              </li>
              <li class="KambiBC-bet-offer-category KambiBC-collapsible-container KambiBC-expanded KambiBC-bet-offer-category--hidden KambiBC-bet-offer-category--fade-in">
                 <header class="KambiBC-bet-offer-category__header" data-touch-feedback="true">
                  <h2 class="KambiBC-bet-offer-category__title js-bet-offer-category-title">Another text</h2>
                 </header>
              </li>

              <li class="KambiBC-bet-offer-category KambiBC-collapsible-container KambiBC-bet-offer-category--hidden KambiBC-bet-offer-category--fade-in">
                 <header class="KambiBC-bet-offer-category__header" data-touch-feedback="true">
                  <h2 class="KambiBC-bet-offer-category__title js-bet-offer-category-title">Different text</h2>
                 </header>
             </li>
                
              <li class="KambiBC-bet-offer-category KambiBC-collapsible-container KambiBC-bet-offer-category--hidden KambiBC-bet-offer-category--fade-in">
                 <header class="KambiBC-bet-offer-category__header" data-touch-feedback="true">
                  <h2 class="KambiBC-bet-offer-category__title js-bet-offer-category-title">Yet another text</h2>
                 </header>
              </li>
                
            </ul>
                  
      
      </div>
```

and this is the Python code:

```html
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Edge("D:\pariuri\python\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.get("https://www.unibet.ro/betting#filter/football")

try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'KambiBC-event-result__score-list'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
    print ('Timed out waiting for page to load') 

event = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('KambiBC-event-item KambiBC-event-item--type-match') 

for items in event:
   link = items.find_element_by_class_name('KambiBC-event-item__link')
   scoruri =  items.find_element_by_class_name('KambiBC-event-item__score-container') 
   
   scor1 =  scoruri.find_element_by_xpath(".//li[@class='KambiBC-event-result__match']/span[1]")
   scor2 =  scoruri.find_element_by_xpath(".//li[@class='KambiBC-event-result__match']/span[2]")
   
   print (scor1.text)
   print (scor2.text)
   if scor1.text == '0' and scor2.text == '0':
       

        link.click()
        time.sleep(3)


        PlajePariuri = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='KambiBC-list-view__column']")
        for items in PlajePariuri:
             NumePlaje = items.find_element_by_xpath("//li/header/h2")
             print (NumePlaje.text)
```

Comment: I don't see any such `text` within the `li` tags as per the HTML provided. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DebanjanB Look at the `<h2>` tags, those have that classname

Comment: The HTML you provided includes only one `<h2>` tag which you are able to retrieve. Unless you provide some more `<h2>` tags it will be tough to derive a dynamic `xpath`

Comment: @DebanjanB every `li` tag has the same `header` and `h2` elements within, and all have the same classnames the first one has, but has different texts

Comment: It's tough to work out an answer based on guesses. Either provide more of the relevant HTML or provide the `url`.

Comment: @DebanjanB i updated the html code

Comment: You didn't mention the manual steps you are trying to automate.

Comment: @DebanjanB Eventually i would like to make a database of certain odds of that site, now i want to get to those odds. Right now they are in the second `li` element from my list. I want to understand the procedure to iterate through webelements lists. What is strange  to me is that the first for loop in my code does what is suppose to do, but the second one is a troublemaker

Comment: @Rius2 the html code is incorrect.  There are many missing closing tags and it appears that there are many nested lists or they are also not closed correctly.  Besides that, your Python code is referencing attributes that do not appear in the HTML snippet at all.  Please provide a valid HTML snippet that corresponds with the Python code you want help with.

Comment: @Breaks Software i provided the relevant HTML snippet for my problem. If you need more i also provided the web adress.

Comment: When I paste that html snippet into an HTML file, it is clearly invalid HTML.  Ok, so let's ignore your snippet and work with the web address in your source code.  Could you please be more specific about where the problem is in your source code?

Comment: The problem would be that the last loop in my code does not iterate through all the elements it from the PlajePariuri list, it prints the text from the first element 3 times and then it exits the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was in my face all along,this will print the text from each element, glad i could find out

```
PlajePariuri = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('KambiBC-bet-offer-category KambiBC-collapsible-container KambiBC-expanded KambiBC-bet-offer-category--hidden KambiBC-bet-offer-category--fade-in')


    for items2 in PlajePariuri:

        NumePlaje = items2.find_element_by_class_name('KambiBC-bet-offer-category__title js-bet-offer-category-title')

        print (NumePlaje.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `classname` locator, try using `xpath` as follows:

```
PlajePariuri = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='KambiBC-list-view__column']")
for items in PlajePariuri:
    NumePlaje = items.find_element_by_xpath("//li/header/h2")
    print (NumePlaje.text)
```

Comment: Interesting, now i get the text from the first element three times and the it exists the loop

Comment: @Rius2 I get the same effect, repeated elements, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @YodaScholtz I found the solution for repeated elements. Not really repeated but the loop wasn't iterating over the `WebElements` properly. Found the answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40067370/4315001)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code-

```
PlajePariuri = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='KambiBC-list-view__column']//li/header/h2")
for items in PlajePariuri:
    print (items.text)
```

Comment: there is more text inside the html code and this will print all thext found, i need the text in between `<h2>` with that specific class name

Comment: @Rius2-- I don't think so. Did you try it?

Comment: I am sure. As i said the actual web page has more element containing more text inside the `ul` list, i posted just the part that i am interested in at the moment. so your code will print everything.I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I did an implementation to find elements inside a list.

My case was we have a wiki with a side list that may have or may not have a list inside a list and so on. 
This is my solution:

```py
// #Create a function to receive the old HTML (Before click), 
// #new HTML (After click), and the element I'm looking for:

def page_handler(old_source,new_source,element):
    new_content = []

    // #Put page into a list (need to verify if it works for you)
    old_page = old_source.split('\n')
    new_page = new_source.split('\n')

    // #Compare the old page and new page. The content of the new page, I check if 
    // #matches with the element I'm looking for

    for data in new_page:
        if data not in old_page:
            if element in data:
                new_content.append(data)

    return new_content

// #Now in the main thread, before the program Click on the item, take a snapshot:
old_page = driver.page_source

// #Click on the item
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text(item).click()

// #take a new snapshot
new_page = driver.page_source

// # Use the function to send the old page and new page, and the class you are looking 
// #for in the HTML code:
new_pg_data = page_handler(old_page,new_page,'class="plugin_pagetree_children_span"')

// # Now I have the children elements, just iterate the list.

for element_id in new_pg_data:
    // #I use regexp to get the element ID
    element_id = search('id="(.*)">  ',element_id)
    if element_id:
        elem = driver.find_element_by_id(element_id).click()
```

I hope this solution can help you guys.