# how to get each element in a class separately in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, curl, selenium-webdriver

There is a website that I want to curl, and data is in nested and separated classes and elements.
each page has a different number of these classes and elements. all I want to get data in a list, as each list element is one of the page elements data.

this is what I've done for it :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path,chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(my_path_to_website)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='class1']/*")
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].textContent;", element)
print(element.text)
```

but it gives me all the data in the parent class as a string, and I want it separated.

here is the form of HTML in the website:

```
<div class="class1" id="class1">    
    <div class="b">
        <div class="m1">
            <p>data1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="m2">
            <p>data2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="b">
        <div class="m1">
            <p>data3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="m2">
            <p>data4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
.
.
.

</div>
```

as I said I want my data in a list `my_data = ['data 1', 'data 2', 'data 3', 'data 4' , ...]` or in a dict ...
but with my code, I just get it as a string. `my_data = "data 1 data 2 data 3 data 4"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okey, I got it :
in my code instead of `find_element_by_xpath` i should use `find_elements_by_xpath`
so it returns me a list of elements, and then :

```
for items in element:
    my_element = items.text
    print (element)
```

thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39520898/10164573) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45995692/10164573).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

```
my_data = driver.execute_script("var myList=[];arguments[0].forEach(function(element) {myList.push(element.textContent);});return myList;",driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".class1 p"))
print(my_data)
```

**Here is the output:**
[image]