# Selenium simple for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use either a for or while loop to loop through the website until the tree is expanded all the way out. All of the closed links names will print; however, my if statement seems to always to never be ran.

```
   for closedLinks in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('closed'):
      #print(closedLinks.text)
       if closedLinks == True:
            closedLinks.click()
            time.sleep(10)
            print(closedLinks)
        else:
            print("FAIL")
```

My current codes output is:

```
           FAIL
           FAIL
           FAIL
           FAIL
           FAIL
           FAIL
           FAIL
           FAIL
           FAIL
           FAIL
           FAIL
```

Collapsed Tree this is what the selenium currently sees:

[image: image of the collapsed tree]

Tree Expanded this is what I'm trying to get:

[image: image of expanded tree]

Comment: what is the value of closedLinks?

Comment: <div id="index__tree" class="index__tree">
<ul class="idx">
<li class="closed"><div class="li"><a href="/doku.php?id=&amp;idx=all" title="all" class="idx_dir"><strong>all</strong></a></div></li>
<li class="closed"><div class="li"><a href="/doku.php?id=&amp;idx=architecture" title="architecture" class="idx_dir"><strong>architecture</strong></a></div></li>

Comment: you are not iterating the web elements correctly, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990851/how-do-i-iterate-through-a-webelements-list-with-python-and-selenium

Comment: Have you tried to use a WebDriverWait prior to the the True and before the sleep?  P.S. I'm not sure the True statement is correct.

Comment: Clearly `closedLinks` is never equal to `True`. Note that comparisons like `if closedLinks == True` can be simplified to `if closedLinks`. This alone probably won't solve your problem, though. Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the IF line:

```
if closedLinks:
```

Answer (score 0):

`closedLinks` is an element, and you are comparing it to the boolean value `True`. They are not equal, so the `else` branch is executed.